# Override onDraw in TextView cause problems in ListView

Tags: android, listview, canvas, textview, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to rotate a TextView, by Overriding onDraw in a class that extends TextView:

```
    // Rotation value 
private float rotation = 0;
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (rotation!=0) { 
        canvas.rotate(rotation, (getWidth()/2), (getHeight()/2));
        canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

It is working well, but my problems starts when I'm using it in a ListView with SherlockActionBar. 
In the getView of the ListView's ArrayAdapter I'm creating a new extended TextView:

```
    TextViewPlus month = (TextViewPlus) rowView.findViewById(R.id.month);
month.setTextRotation(-90);
month.setText("MAR");
```

The TextView get rotated very well, but when I scroll the ListView it overlay the ActionBar! Is seems that it is leaving a track on it!

[image: Overlay during scrolling]

Why is that? How can I solve it?

Comment: My guess would be that your TextViewPlus class is giving the wrong dimensions. Do you override onMeasure(int, int), onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) and onSizeChanged(int, int, int, int) in your custom view?

Comment: I'm not overriding onMeasure or onLayout or onSizeChanged. I'm trying now to override onMeasure and use measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()); but it is not helping.

Comment: By the way, in the emulator this problem do not exist...